# Last digit of a large number test cases fail in Golang Codewars

Tags: algorithm, go, equation-solving

> Define a function that takes in two non-negative integers *a* and *b* and returns the last decimal digit of *a*<sup>*b*</sup>.
> Note that *a* or *b* may be very large!
> You may assume that the input will always be valid.

```
package kata

import (
    "math"
    "strconv"
)


func ParseInt(n string) int {
    num, _ := strconv.ParseInt(n, 10, 64)
    return int(num)
}

func LastDigit(n1, n2 string) int {
    exponent := ParseInt(n2)
    if exponent == 0 {
        return 1
    }
  
    num := int(ParseInt(string(n1[len(n1)-1])))
  
    var lastDigit int
    if num%2 == 0 {
        lastDigit = 6
    } else {
        lastDigit = 1
    }
  
    switch n1[len(n1)-1] {
    case '0', '1', '5', '6':
        return num
    case '4', '9':
        if exponent%2 == 0 {
            return lastDigit
        }
        return num
    default:
        remainder := exponent % 4
        if remainder == 0 {
            return lastDigit
        }
        result := int(math.Pow(float64(num), float64(reminder))) * lastDigit % 10
        return result
    }
}
```

Test case err: expect 7 equal to 1
Test case err: expect 3 equal to 1

I tried in my *Code Editor*, everything works seemly right.
But it still failed some test cases.

Comment: Don't mix float operators (e.g. Pow) with integers. Precision will be lost. Better figure out an algorithm to calculate just the last digit. For example, use only the last digit of `a`.

Comment: Just a reminder: division may leave a *rem**a**inder*.

Comment: I guess b can be very small, too.

Answer (score 1):

the last digit of the power result actually follows a sequence.
Here is a super efficient function to calculate what you want:

```
func test(n1 int64, n2 int64) int {
    result := 1

    if n2 == 0 {
        return result
    }

    var lastDigitsMap = make(map[int][]int)

    lastDigitsMap[0] = []int{0}
    lastDigitsMap[1] = []int{1}
    lastDigitsMap[2] = []int{6, 2, 4, 8}
    lastDigitsMap[3] = []int{1, 3, 9, 7}
    lastDigitsMap[4] = []int{6, 4}
    lastDigitsMap[5] = []int{5}
    lastDigitsMap[6] = []int{6}
    lastDigitsMap[7] = []int{1, 7, 9, 3}
    lastDigitsMap[8] = []int{6, 8, 4, 2}
    lastDigitsMap[9] = []int{1, 9}

    n1LastDigit := int(n1 % 10)
    ldIndex := int(n2 % int64(len(lastDigitsMap[n1LastDigit])))
    result = lastDigitsMap[n1LastDigit][ldIndex]

    return result
}
```